# Backbone model on save only returns form data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, laravel

In a web application I am building, I save a model via an API - on success I return the model to the console, however the model only contains the data submitted from the form, but yet the API saves various other pieves of data created from the submitted form, how can I get the full model to be return in success callback?

here is my code,

MOdel save,

```
saveBasicProject: function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var that = this;

    console.log("saving basic project");

    var projectData = $('.create-new-project').serializeJSON();

    //var projectModel = new app.Project(projectData);

    this.model.save(projectData, {

        success: function(model, response) {
            console.log(model);
            that.response_json = JSON.parse(response);
            that.collection.add(that.model);
        },

        error: function(model, response) {
            var error_json = response.responseJSON;

            $(".create-new-project").before( response.responseJSON.msg );

        }

    });

},
```

API save

```
public function save()
{
    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'cost' => 'numeric',
        'start_date' => 'required | date',
        'end_date' => 'required | date'
    );  

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validation->fails()) {
        return Response::json( $validation->messages()->first(), 500);

    } else {

        $project = new Project;

        $project->name = Input::get('name');
        $project->description = Input::get('description');
        $project->total_cost = Input::get('cost');
        $project->start_date = Input::get('start_date');
        $project->finish_date = Input::get('end_date');
        $project->run_number_days = $this->get_days_between_two_dates(Input::get('start_date'), Input::get('end_date'));
        $project->num_days_from_year_start = $this->get_days_between_two_dates("2014-01-01", Input::get('start_date'));
        $project->color = $this->project_rbg_to_project_hex();
        $project->user_id = ResourceServer::getOwnerId();

        if( $project->save() ) {

            return Response::json($project, 200);

        } else {

            return Response::json(array( 'error' => 'Something has gone wrong!' ), 500);

        }

    }

}
```

What gets returned?

```
    child {cid: "c60", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object attributes: Object cost: "18000" description: "Description" end_date: "2014/01/30" name: "Simon 18" start_date: "2014/01/01"
__proto__: Object changed: Object cid: "c60" collection: child
__proto__: Surrogate
```

The POST json

```
{cost: "23000"
description: "Description"
end_date: "2014/01/30"
name: "Project #23"
start_date: "2014/01/01"}
```

The response from the server

```
{
    name: "Project#23",
    description: "Description",
    total_cost: 23000,
    start_date: "2014/01/01",
    finish_date: "2014/01/30",
    run_number_days: 30,
    num_days_from_year_start: 1,
    color: "#757da3",
    user_id: 1,
    updated_at: "2014-08-0510: 14: 15",
    created_at: "2014-08-0510: 14: 15",
    id: 105
}
```

The above is also getting updated in the DB but the model that gets returned just includes the original request json.

Comment: Tell us... What you are sending? What you are receiving in response? And What is getting updated in Model on success? JSON for all these 3 will be good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set the response data to model in success callback.

e.g.

```
that.model.set(that.response_json);
```

Comment: really? This is not something that Backbone does intelligently. i.e Save a model generally means I want the model back?

Comment: Different back-end services may have different behavior. It is not guaranteed that the server returns back a copy of the model's attributes, or that any changes were made. Your use case may be common, but it is the exception not the rule. `Model.save` is for persisting the state of a model, if you anticipate changes from the server you should update the model on success.